# Hide uilabel, uiswitch while Uiactivity indicator spinning

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Is there i way that i can hide uilabel and uiswitch while the ui activity indicator spinning and then when it stops uilabel and uiswitch apper

Comment: label.hidden = YES; switch.hidden=YES; then, label.hidden=NO, switch.hidden=NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `hidden` property of those views to `YES` wherever you call 
`[spinner startAnimating];` and to `NO` at `[spinner stopAnimating];`

Comment: oh, i didnt know it could be that easy, tnx !

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on the hollow tick if it's helped you.